# LT_VERSION for libtool and autoconf not being recognized

Tags: c++, autoconf, libtool, autoreconf

My configure.in file has **LT_VERSION="1.1"**. I am using the latest version of autoconf and libtool. While using autoconf or autoreconf, I am getting the following error message:

```
configure.ac:41: error: possibly undefined macro: LT_VERSION
  If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
  See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot find any reference to LT_VERSION in the libtool source tree (there is an LTVERSION,
and an LTOBSOLETE_VERSION), so I'm assuming that string in your configure.in (which should be renamed configure.ac) is a private string and not something used by libtool.  In that case, there are 2 things you should do.  First, you should change the name, since you are stomping on libtool's namespace and it appears that LT_VERSION is used by libtool (in fact, it looks like an m4 macro provided by libtool, and assigning to it is therefore really odd).  Second, you should use m4_pattern_allow.  (See the autoconf documentation.)  In other words, put this in your configure.ac:

```
m4_pattern_allow([LT_VERSION])
```

That will suppress the warning.